# [Solved]Cannot override Pdf/Total/Default.php model

Tags: extensions, overrides, model, magento-1, pdf

Good morning everybody!

I have a problem trying to override the model `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/Default.php` with `app/code/local/Mycompany/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/Default.php`.

The thing is that when I rewrite the module but Magento is using the old module without override.

Here I upload the relevant codes:

- `etc/modules/Mycompany_Sales.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Sales>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Sales />
            </depends>
        </Mycompany_Sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

- `app/code/local/Mycompany/Sales/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Sales>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Sales>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_pdf_total_default>Mycompany_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default</order_pdf_total_default>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

- `code/local/Mycompany/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/Default.php`

```
<?php
class Mycompany_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default
{
    public function getFullTaxInfo()
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

I have compared it with some internet examples of models overriding and everything seems to be alright.

Anyone knows what can be the problem?

Thank you very much!!

[EDIT]

Finally I have solved the problem.
The thing is that there is a core file `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Pdf/Grandtotal.php` that overrides `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Order/Pdf/Total/Default.php` so my extended class was in conflict with the tax class.

For solving it I rewrite my extension in order to extends `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Pdf/Grandtotal.php`.

The result is:
 - `etc/modules/Mycompany_Sales.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Sales>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Sales />
                <Mage_Tax />
            </depends>
        </Mycompany_Sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

- `app/code/local/Mycompany/Sales/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Sales>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Sales>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <tax>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_pdf_grandtotal>Mycompany_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default</sales_pdf_grandtotal>
                </rewrite>
            </tax>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

- `code/local/Mycompany/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/Default.php`

```
<?php
class Mycompany_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default extends Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Pdf_Grandtotal
{
    public function getFullTaxInfo()
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Did flush the cache ? Recompile if you're using compiler ? What do you get if you type `get_class(Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_total_default'));` ?

Comment: Yes, I have flush the chache and it does not solve the problem.

Comment: What about the code I pasted ? Which result did you get from this ?

Comment: When I use `get_class(Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_total_default'));` a weird thing happens, it shows my class `Mycompany_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default` instead the old one.

Comment: That means your class is properly overwritten as your module code suggests. What makes your think that your model is not being used ?

Comment: Because of the pdf result. There is a section in the pdf that says: "ESP 21 (21.0000%)". If I truncate the number in the Mage model the result is "ESP 21 (21%)", but if I truncate the number in my class it displays "ESP 21 (21.0000%)" as if I wouldn't  have changed anything.

Comment: I tried override directly in the core module `$percent = get_class(Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_total_default'));` and keep my extension unmodified. The thing is that it shows me "ESP 21 Mycompany_..." and if I do get_class($this) shows me `Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Pdf_Grandtotal`that is not the class in which I am in.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not working because of sales group name. It conflicts with Magento core sales module.

Use below code

**app/etc/modules/Mycompany_Customsales.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycompany_Customsales>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mycompany_Customsales>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Mycompany/Customsales/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycompany_Customsales>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mycompany_Customsales>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <customsales>
        <class>Mycompany_Customsales_Helper</class>
      </customsales>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <customsales>
        <class>Mycompany_Customsales_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>customsales_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </customsales>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_pdf_total_default>Mycompany_Customsales_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Total_Default</order_pdf_total_default>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

Model: **app/code/local/Mycompany/Customsales/Model/Sales/Order/Pdf/Total/Default.php**

```
<?php
class Mycompany_Customsales_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Total_Default extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default
{
     //add your code
}
```

Hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: I tried to copy the code above and flush cache but nothing seems to change.

Comment: Have you changed module group name ?

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what Adrian Gallego Castellanos edited into his post, I wasn't able to successfully override `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Pdf/Grandtotal.php`.

I had to extend `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Pdf/Tax.php` instead so I could override the `getFullTaxInfo()` function found in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Order/Pdf/Total/Default.php`.